# Java using Rome and SyndEntry to retrive "getType" field of URL

Tags: java, feed, rome

I am using Rome and SyndEntry(com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndEntry) to retrive "getType" field of URL.

Here is the sample xml feed.

```
<entry>
  <title>Best Sellers</title>
 <link type="application/atom+xml;profile=opds-catalog;kind=acquisition" 
    href="http://www.feedbooks.com/store/top.atom" rel="http://opds-spec.org
/sort/popular"/>
  <updated>2014-03-27T16:38:38Z</updated>
 <id>http://www.feedbooks.com/books/top.atom?range=week</id>
 <content type="text">All categories</content>
</entry>
```

I want to get this: 
    link type="application/atom+xml;profile=opds-catalog;kind=acquisition"

I tried with below code:

```
        SyndEntry entry = getItem( index );
        List<SyndEnclosure> enclosureList = (List<SyndEnclosure>)entry.getEnclosures();
        Log.d("opds", "size:"+enclosureList.size());
        for (SyndEnclosure enclosure : enclosureList) {
            Log.d("opds", enclosure.getType());
        }
```

But it returns enclosureList.size() is zero.
What is the correct way to get the link->Type field? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
        List<SyndLink> links = entry.getLinks();
        for (SyndLink link : links) {
            System.out.println(link.getType());
        }
```

Comment: thanks, it works. but i would like to know more, how can i get entry->title, entry->updated, entry->content, entry->link->rel? thanks.

Comment: The SyndEntry interface has methods for retrieving those values: [SyndEntry javadoc](http://rometools.github.io/rome/apidocs/com/sun/syndication/feed/synd/SyndEntry.html)

Comment: thanks, i can get title, content, link, if i want to get <summary>xxx</summary>, is it using org.jdom2.Element? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844634/java-using-rome-to-get-entry-summary

Comment: oh, i found it out, it is getDescription()